# Hide Rows with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to using Apps Script.
I'm trying to automate a function to hide empty rows based on a dropdown selection but it does not seem to fully function. I get one to work but when I select another class it does not hide the correct rows. It stays hiding the rows (35,2)

Please Help!
Here is the script thanks:

```
function hideRow()
{

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Attendance Register');
var dropDown = sheet.getRange("G12").getValue();

if(dropDown == "GED 211 Academic Writing")
{
sheet.hideRows(35,2);

}
else if(dropDown == "FS101 Freshman Seminar")
{
sheet.hideRows(24,13);

}

else if(dropDown == "GED000B Foundation English I")
{
sheet.hideRows(23,14);

}
else if(dropDown == "GED001 Foundation Mathematics II")
{
sheet.hideRows(22,15);

}
else if(dropDown == "GED003 Fundamentals in Hospitality and Tourism")
{
sheet.hideRows(24,13);

}
else
{

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `showRows()` function at the start of your script to unhide all the rows first.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showrowsrowindex

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that.